# Store the result of an sql query to a variable (without For each) (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, foreach

I'm new to Laravel and i need your help please.

This runs on my controller and the result should be "3" as long as I have 3 rows with that title in the same table.

```
 $countcategories = DB::table('categories')
                ->select(DB::raw('count(title) as result'))
                ->where('title','=','dsds')
                ->get();
```

I'm passing the query result to the view like this`->with('counts', $countcategories)`

And now my questions are:

1. In the view I can only display the result by using `foreach`. Why? My query returns only one row.
2. I want to store the query result in a variable inside my controller in order to use that result. How can I do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can also do a `->toArray()` after `get()` to get an array of models accessible through numerical index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use ->first() method:

```
$countcategories = DB::table('categories')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(title) as result'))
            ->where('title','=','dsds')
            ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What you are `get`ting are rows from a result, it tunrs out there is only one in your situation.
2. You have already done that.

Anyways, here's my approach:

```
// The result
$categories = Category::where('title','=','dsds');
foreach( $categories->all() as $category ) {
    echo $category->title . "\n";
}

// The count
echo $categories->count();
```